# how can i keep all h3 headings the same height regardless of content?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have several spans inside a row in twitter bootstrap. inside these spans are `<h3>` headers and then `<img>`, `<p>`, etc. some of theses headers may only have one or two words. some may have 5 or 6 words which causes greater height. this makes the remaining content look wonky on the page because the images are higher or lower than the rest. how can i make all of the header tags keep the same height based on the amount of content in the largest header? or how can i make the content in the larger header shrink down to a size to keep the same height? i dont think this last approach is really what i need. the smaller text would probably look as wonky as the initial problem.

another problem this causes is due to the amount of content that may be displayed at any time, i may have more spans than than the row calls for. IE: 6 span4's. this makes the last two drop down and begin their own "row" inside the row. that's fine and needed, but if the second span4 drops lower than the others i end up with the two lower spans pushed to the right because they cant slip past that span. and if the third span is lower then i end up with one span to the far right and a third row with one span to the far left. bad wonky!!!

i need a css option that i can add to my own css file separate from the bootstrap and responsive css files. i have a class refering to these spans specificly for text color, etc. so it doesnt effect any other `<h3>` tags

code:

```
<div class="hero-unit">
<h1>Opening This Week!</h1>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3 mobile-two"><h3>The Incredible Burt Wonderstone</h3><img src="img/ads/incredburtwonderstone-onesht.jpg"></div>
    <div class="span3 mobile-two"><h3>test small</h3><img src="img/ads/incredburtwonderstone-onesht.jpg"></div>
    <div class="span3 mobile-two"><h3>The Incredible Burt Wonderstone</h3><img src="img/ads/incredburtwonderstone-onesht.jpg"></div>
    <div class="span3 mobile-two"><h3>The Incredible Burt Wonderstone</h3><img src="img/ads/incredburtwonderstone-onesht.jpg"></div>
    <div class="span3 mobile-two"><h3>The Incredible Burt Wonderstone</h3><img src="img/ads/incredburtwonderstone-onesht.jpg"></div>
    <div class="span3 mobile-two"><h3>The Incredible Burt Wonderstone</h3><img src="img/ads/incredburtwonderstone-onesht.jpg"></div>
    <div class="span3 mobile-two"><h3>The Incredible Burt Wonderstone</h3><img src="img/ads/incredburtwonderstone-onesht.jpg"></div>
    <div class="span3 mobile-two"><h3>The Incredible Burt Wonderstone</h3><img src="img/ads/incredburtwonderstone-onesht.jpg"></div>
    <div class="span3 mobile-two"><h3>The Incredible Burt Wonderstone</h3><img src="img/ads/incredburtwonderstone-onesht.jpg"></div>
    <div class="span3 mobile-two"><h3>The Incredible Burt Wonderstone</h3><img src="img/ads/incredburtwonderstone-onesht.jpg"></div>
    <div class="span3 mobile-two"><h3>The Incredible Burt Wonderstone</h3><img src="img/ads/incredburtwonderstone-onesht.jpg"></div>
</div>
<p>These movies open this Friday!</p>
<p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-small" href="#coming-soon">See Showtimes &raquo;</a></p></div>
```

---link removed

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/GyYMK/1

Comment: Can you show some code? An example page perhaps? Can't really help if we don't have anything visual or code to look at. For your problem, maybe you can try min-height. Else please provide code or example.

Comment: i removed the link due to using that address for development

Comment: I looked at your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/GyYMK/1/, but am not really seeing the problem that you're describing. Maybe I overlooked it.

Comment: (S)he wants the images aligned vertically.

Comment: he. :) that's exactly right. in the jsfiddle -thanks @isherwood!- you have to drag the viewport wider until it takes on a desktop view. then you can see one of the images move up with the header. i was looking for a way to keep them all inline, but it would have to cross divs to do so. originally i just placed the header below the picture to resolve this. however, now i have placed the title inside a button.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a min-height on the h3 elements, but that's a rather fragile approach and breaks if the page goes narrow enough that they wrap to more lines than you had planned for:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/GyYMK/3/

```
.mobile-two h3 {
    min-height: 120px;
}
```

You may want to write some jQuery to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to look at this more as a 'design' issue rather than a 'css' issue. You could probably take advantage of the asymmetry that gets created with this layout. A nice example is Pinterest. They have a similar challenge (not with the text) but with the heights of the images people upload. You could do something similar by distributing content in vertical columns by declaring the 'span3' div as a holder of movie posters:

```
<div class="span3 mobile-two movies-column">
    <div class="movie-tn">
        <h3>The Incredible Burt Wonderstone</h3>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x100" />
    </div>
    <!--more movie poster holders-->
</div>
```

Here s a JSFiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/R5qJ9/

You will need to do some calculation to distribute the movie posters in the columns though. But then you d have to do some calculation to set uniform heights as well.

A little enhancement would be to rearrange the image and the header and add some content related to the movie to spread out the design elements a little:

Here s a JSFiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/yQp6h/